# Key recognition speed in dictionaries

Tags: c#, performance, loops, dictionary

I have a rather general question regarding the recognition speed of any dictionary using a string as a key and couldn't find an answer so far.

Within my current program I have a dictionary of custom objects but the keys I use are filenames including the whole path of the file such that no key can actually occur twice.

My question is: Does the time to find the specific object within the dictionary significantly depend on the length of the string used as a key? Afterall, if I have a big amount of data saved within my object and I use that data in a loop and access the data every single time by using `myDictionary[Key]`. The simple recognition might take a long time, making the loops last for a longer time.

My solution to this problem would be: In case of using an array, lets say `double[,,]` within my object, I temporarily create a new array and set this one equal to the one within the dictionary, so I don't have to search through the dictionary for every single loop iteration.

Comment: "such that no key can actually occur twice" ... Using a `Dictionary` is not safe. `c:\myfile.ext`==`C:\myfile.ext`==`c:\someDir\..\mYfILe.ExT` but these would all be distinct keys in your dictionary. Make sure you reduce your filenames to their canonical version. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I took care of problems as you described. All keys are generated in exactly the same way such that different file names for the same file will not occur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the time to find the specific object within the dictionary
>   significantly depend on the length of the string used as a key?

Yes it does. Finding an element in a dictionary is done with two CPU intensive steps:

1. Generate the hash code for the key.
2. Comparing all elements in the same bucket by equality.

A dictionary stores elements in buckets. To be able to do an [O(1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) lookup, the dictionary calculates the position in the internal array using `hashCode modulo array.Length`. This can result in elements with the same index. Those elements are stored under the same index; which is called a bucket.

For a string, the hash code is generated using all characters in the string, which mean that the generation of the string's hash code has a performance characteristic of O(n). When the string is big, it takes longer to generate the hash code. Comparing to strings for equality is done by comparing two strings completely. If these strings contain, let's say, 100,000 characters and only the last character differs, comparing the two strings can take quite a lot of time. If they differ with the first character, the comparison will return false very quickly. Determining that two strings are in fact equal (if they aren't reference equal) takes the most time, since the complete string needs to be traversed.

If you can, make key strings short if the dictionary is in a performance critical path of the application.

Comment: As I already commented on Thorten Dittmar's answer: You both seem to say contradictory things, as it does not really depend on the length on the string but only on the hash code. Does the creation of the hash code simply take longer for longer strings?

Comment: It takes longer to generate the hash code of a longer string. Getting strings from a dictionary is O(1), but this doesn't say it can get slow. What O(1) means is that the operation will not get slower when the dictionary contains many elements.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Thorsten just said the same thing. At the moment I will stick to using the filename strings but is good to know for future projects.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**
The wording of my answer was a bit misleading - trying to clear that up.

In theory, looking up in a dictionary/hashtable should be an O(1) process if the hash function produces ideal hash codes (meaning that for each unique input the output is also unique). If two input strings generate the same hash code (the hash function is *not* ideal), a list of entries ("bucket") is created for that hash code, which must then be searched item by item.

So, once the hash code is created, looking up the bucket in theory is an O(1) operation. Searching the bucket is an O(n) operation, where n is the number of elements in the bucket.

The string length influences:

1. The creation of the hash code. The longer the string, the longer it takes to create the hash code.
2. Bucket search: When searching the bucket item by item, the string length of course matters, too, as it is the key for the search.

So: *Yes*, the string length actually does matter.

The real question is whether a dictionary is really the right tool in your situation, given that you say you frequently iterate over all the keys in the dictionary. In that case, using a list of objects (containing the file name and other data) and preventing the insertion of duplicates by looking up the file name upon each insertion might be way faster if you insert rarely but lookup often.

Comment: Now your answer seems different to the one by Steven who says the hash code actually depends on the length of the string, making the recognition last longer.

Comment: As Steven says, "recognition" is a two step process: Generate the hash over the string (which is faster for shorter strings) and then look up in the dictionary. I said that given an ideal hash function looking up is an O(1) operation. However, in cases where two input strings generate the same hash, looking up *the bucket* is an O(1) process and then searching within the bucket is an O(n) operation. So yes, the string length matters.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. In my case it is not really a big issue yet, but good to know for the future.
edit to your edit: I don't loop over the dictionary, I loop over the data within one single dictionary object, which has at the point of use not much to do with the filename.

Comment: Don't forget that since strings can not be compared by their hash code, the dictionary always has to compare the strings, even if there's only one string in that bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, shorter strings perform better than longer ones. But performance impact is very limited (until you have million of get).
You can try a micro bench or read [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-string-key)